# Install Sphinxsearch on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: yum, elastic-beanstalk, sphinxsearch

How do I install [Sphinx search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) in an Elasticbeanstalk container so that it is automatically installed anytime the instance restarts?. 
I tried this container command in my `.config` of the `.ebextensions` folder but it did not work.

```
container_commands:
  01_install_sphinx:
    command: curl -L -o sphinx-2.2.6-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm  http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.6-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm && sudo yum -y install ./sphinx-2.2.6-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm && sudo chkconfig searchd on
```

Comment: define 'didnt work'. Thats not very specific. Do you get a specific error? A partly working install what? Can you check logs?

Comment: I finally got it to work. I don't know exactly what happened, but when i created another instance, it worked fine. i just had to add `ignoreErrors: true` to it.